# Refreshing firebase when in background

Tags: swift, firebase

I am currently making an app where users can send messages to their counselors at camp, without releasing their phone numbers. If the user sends a message, how can I check on the counselors app if they received a message, and if so, display a push notification, even if the app is in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Apple Push Notification Service (APNS).

To do this you will need a BaaS server with some PHP code and certificates to access Apple's servers.  Each device authenticates to the APNS server when the app is loaded and provided a key.  Then the device sending a message will send a request to your server and the server will process the data through Apple to whichever remote tokens you have specified in the payload.

Great write up here... https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/